# All I know vs. Alls I know

Tags: american-english, speech

Are the two sayings proper English?

> "Alls I know"

and

> "All I know"

Alls I know just sounds bad to me, but while people agree, no one can tell me if it is right or wrong.

Comment: A lot of people will actually write or say "all as I know" or "all is I know".. Best just to say "all that I know" or "all I know"

Comment: I don't know an English word "alls".

Comment: @Colin One overall, two overalls—or if we wish to exaggerate less and be understatingly British about it: one all, two alls. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alls** is always wrong, except perhaps in some dialectal phrases.

Comment: Notably, _alls I know_ is a very common dialectal phrase. It exists in quite a few dialects, and as long as you're speaking one of those dialects, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: A language is a dialect with an army.

Answer (score 1):

I ran Google Books searches on “alls I know,” “alls I can,” and various related phrases—and I was surprised to see how recent the attested usage is. The first Google Books match is from 1958. From Reynolds Price, “[A Chain of Love](http://books.google.com/books?id=IG8OAAAAMAAJ&q=%22alls+I+know+is+they+ain%27t+many+lives%22&dq=%22alls+I+know+is+they+ain%27t+many+lives%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WkgHVIuIBZKOyATe1oDICg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ) (Encounter, March 1958), reprinted in *Light Blue Dark Blue: An Anthology of Recent Writing from Oxford and Cambridge Universities* (1960) [snippet]:

> Papa wanted to know, "Is he going to live, Snowball?"
>
> "Can't say, Mr. Mustian. He spit the first blood to-day, and **alls I know** is they ain't many lives past that. They ain't many. And if they lives you almost wish they hadn't. That's how bad they gets before it's over."

The next-earliest matches are from 1972. From [United States v. Rispo](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xgs4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22alls+i+know%22&dq=%22alls+i+know%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FUsHVKT_Dsq9igKt-4GYDg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCTgK), published in *Federal Supplement [First Series]*, volume 338 (1972) [combined snippets]:

> First, the incident about which Zimmie was cross-examined occurred but one month after the crimes at bar; it was not until May, 1970 that the indictment in the case at bar was brought. Not in January 1969 would, nor until May, 1970 could, the crimes at bar affect defendant's reputation in the community. Secondly, the crimes at bar cannot have influenced Zimmie's conclusions as to the community's opinion because he said during cross-examination, "**Alls I know**, they can talk good about the boy; I don't know anything bad." (N.T. p. 383). It is evident that this aspect of the cross-examination was proper under the circumstances and did not prejudice the defendant James Rispo.

And from New Jersey State Commission of Investigation, [*Appendix to the Report on the Investigation of the Office of the Attorney General of the State of New Jersey*](http://books.google.com/books?id=iZ1CAAAAIAAJ&q=%22alls+i+can%22&dq=%22alls+i+can%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fU4HVMPLLMi6iwLig4DoBA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBzgK), volume 1 (1972):

> EXAMINATION BY THE CHAIRMAN: Q[:] I've got one question, while I'm thinking of it, Mr. Schuyler. Among your bidders in this project and knowing that there were probably aware that the Federal Highway Administration was to review your plans - I'm sure they were aware of that, right?
>
> A[:] Mr. McCarthy, I can't specifically answer that. I don't know. **Alls I can do** is tell you that I believe it was not common knowledge up until the day that we advertised this contract or this work that was ...

Price’s 1958 short story is set in rural North Carolina, while both of the 1972 occurrences involve testimony by people living in New Jersey. So if “alls I know” (or “alls I can do”) is dialect speech, it may have arisen independently in at least two very different parts of the country.

Answer (score -2):

The word 'all' is a pronoun and does not have a plural form or 'all' itself can be plural.

Please take a look where 'all' as a pronoun is describes in the dictionary below.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all?show=0&t=1409761685

Answer (score -4):

The "'s" is possibly a contraction for "as." That would qualify the "all," making it "all as I know [it] is blah blah blah."

In other words, the phrase would mean "all--as far as I know-- is blah blah blah."

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for this, or are you just guessing? Was *all as I know* ever a common phrase?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and answers are expected to be definitive rather than speculative. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.